# importing the wx module in python

Tags: python, import, module, wxwidgets

When I import the wx module in a python interpreter it works as expect. However, when I run a script (ie. test.py) with wx in the imports list, I need to write "python test.py" in order to run the script. If I try to execute "test.py" I get an import error saying there is no module named "wx". Why do I need to include the word python in my command?

PS the most helpful answer I found was "The Python used for the REPL is not the same as the Python the script is being run in. Print sys.executable to verify." but I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Write a two line script (named showexe.py for example):

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

Run it both ways as `showexe.py` and `python showexe.py`.  It will tell you if you're using the same executable in both cases.  If not, then it'll depend on your operating system what you have to do to make the two run the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your script with something like #!/usr/local/bin/python (but using the path to your python interpreter) you can run it without including python in your command, like a bash script.